# inline paragraph element with line break does not remain inline

Tags: html, css, image, inline, paragraph

So my issue is as follows.

I have a div that contains both an image and a div (which contains text). The text contains a title and additional content, separated by a line break. See below or my attached codepen for an example.

```
<div class="outer">
  <img src="something.com/pic.png">
  <div class="inner">
    Title<br>Additional text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [code pen](http://codepen.io/davidcarlsoncode/pen/YPpXmY)

When I apply display styling of inline to the inner div, the title is inline with the bottom of the image and the text following the linebreak is below the image. Furthermore, if I wrap the text in paragraph tags, all of the text is below the image.

I would like the title to appear at the top and to the right of the image, and all content of the inner div to remain at that alignment, even if the text extends past the height of the image. Furthermore, in the future I will be adding a div with an additional image and more text inside the inner div beneath the text that is already present, and I wish for that content to maintain the same alignment.

Here is my end goal:

[image: Desired Result]

And my desired html structure:

```
<div>
    <img>
    <!--Start right indent (from top right of image) -->
    <div>
        <p>Title<br>text</p>
        <div>
            <img>
            <div>
                <p>Title<br>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End right indent -->
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like display: inline-block will place it inline with the image, but in some instances where the text is longer it appears below, and it still does not cause the text to start at the top right of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I have found the solution.

```
.post img{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.post_content{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}
```

My codepen: [Code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJNmbK)